# IE 11 Window.opener.dispatchEvent throws SCRIPT87: Invalid Argument

Tags: javascript, events, internet-explorer-11

I have parent window which opening another window. In the child window I am trying to send event to the opener. My code look like this:

```
export function taskClose(opener: string) {
if (!window.opener || window.opener === window || window.opener.closed) {
        redirectToPath(opener);
        return;
    }

var updateEvent;
if (typeof(Event) === 'function') {
    updateEvent = new Event('inboxNeedUpdate');
}else {
    updateEvent = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
    updateEvent.initCustomEvent('inboxNeedUpdate', false, false, undefined);
}
window.opener.dispatchEvent(updateEvent);
window.close();}
```

I would like to know how to correctly dispatch event to opener window.
This code correctly works in Chrome and FF.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Any resolutions to this?

Comment: After scouring the web, I personally don't believe there is a polyfill to replicate the behaviour one would expect. It seems like `dispatchEvent()` in IE11 [doesn't work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener) with `window.opener`. I think my only option is to refactor so that there is no longer a reference to `window.opener`.

Comment: i am facing the similar issue

Answer (score 1):

Need to reference the originating window or else it rejects the event

```
window.opener.document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
```